# Spring + ReactJS ERRCONNRESET

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, websocket

i am working on a ReactJS app with a Spring backend server which provides the data. The data is passed via Websockets. Some Snippets from the Spring side of things:

```
@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate template;
.
.
EditorObject obj = new EditorObject();
template.convertAndSend("/update/editor", obj);
```

In the ReactJS part the websocket is connected via

```
const editorSocket = new SockJS("/websocket")
    const editorClient = Stomp.over(editorSocket)
    editorClient.debug = null
    editorClient.connect({}, () => {
      console.log("im connect")
      editorSubscription = editorClient.subscribe("/update/editor", (msg) => {
    // do sth
    })
```

What i am trying to do is work on the project in the development mode via npm start. I added

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

to my package.json. Everything works fine in production but when I access the app via npm start on the port 3000 i get the following error in console:

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /websocket/602/m05cnhhq/xhr?t=1675349479939 from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:8080.
```

See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).

Any help is appreciated, having to build to see any changes applied is atrocious.

I have also researched a bit, this seems to be caused by my Spring server cutting the connection. I don't see anything in the server's output that looks anything like that. The only warning i get is

```
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] with preset Content-Type 'text/event-stream;charset=UTF-8']
```

Comment: If you are using create-react-app, this is a [known issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5280)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer :) At least now i know its not an issue on my part :D